# Spring mail - username in form of an email

Tags: java, spring, email

I want to be able to use my own email address at my own domain in my application.

I have defined the following:

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.username=example
spring.mail.password=*****
spring.mail.protocol=smtp
spring.mail.port=587
```

Which works great. However, when I am switching to my own domain, and set the info:

```
spring.mail.host=da16.domeny.com
spring.mail.username=contact@mydomain.com
spring.mail.password=*****
spring.mail.protocol=smtp
spring.mail.port=587
```

Console reads:

2016-09-01 15:16:37,475 ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]:

> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path
>   [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages:
>   javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;   nested exception
>   is:   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 Nieprawidlowy
>   adres nadawcy / incorrect envelope address ; message exceptions (1)
>   are: Failed message 1: javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid
>   Addresses;

When I am trying to send an email. My domain provider says to specify my full email in username when I am trying to connect using smtp. Any ideas why it may not be working?

Comment: When I had a similar problem, I always try the connect-data in my favorite eMail client (thunderbird). I would guess that the host is not correct. Are you sure that the active smtp-server is on this host?

Comment: Add the full stacktrace instead of a snippet and use code tags for it not comment tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the domain provider was not able to send my email, because I didn't set '`from`' field in the `MimeMessageHelper`. I was surprised, as GMail account didn't required that.